# Customize sankey diagram in R

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets, networkd3

Using `sankeyNetwork()` in package [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3), I want to customize the resulting diagram a little bit. The reproducible code is as following:

```
library(networkD3)

links <- data.frame(source = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3), target = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7), value = c(70, 56.4, 48.7, 0.9, 338.8, 50.8, 5.6, 47.3, 1.4))
nodes <- data.frame(name = c("Cu in obsolete TVs", "Illegal export", " Domestic recycling", "Open burning", "Dumping landfill", "Reuse", "Material recovery", "Material loss"))

sankeyNetwork(Links=links, Nodes=nodes, Source='source', Target='target',
          Value='value', NodeID='name', fontSize=16, sinksRight = FALSE)
```

I want to customize the resulting graph in the following ways:

1. I want to move the label "Cu in obsolete TVs" to the left of the box for its corresponding node.
2. I want to double the width of the box for Reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The customizations you want are not possible using the built-in options of `networkD3`, but you can achieve them by using [htmlwidgets](/questions/tagged/htmlwidgets) `onRender()` to run custom JavaScript when it loads. For example (also increased the right margin in the `sankeyNetwork()` function so the left justified label is not cut off):

```
library(networkD3)
library(htmlwidgets)

links <- data.frame(source = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3), target = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7), value = c(70, 56.4, 48.7, 0.9, 338.8, 50.8, 5.6, 47.3, 1.4))
nodes <- data.frame(name = c("Cu in obsolete TVs", "Illegal export", " Domestic recycling", "Open burning", "Dumping landfill", "Reuse", "Material recovery", "Material loss"))
sn <- sankeyNetwork(Links=links, Nodes=nodes, Source='source', Target='target',
              Value='value', NodeID='name', fontSize=16, sinksRight = FALSE, 
              margin = list(right = 150))

onRender(sn,
  '
  function(el,x) {
    d3.select(el)
      .selectAll(".node text")
      .filter(function(d) { return d.name == "Cu in obsolete TVs"; })
      .attr("x", x.options.nodeWidth - 16)
      .attr("text-anchor", "end");

    d3
      .selectAll("rect")
      .filter(function (d, i) { return i === 5;})
      .attr("width", x.options.nodeWidth * 2);
  }
  '
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much CJ Yetman. Also for your previous answer in another post, I found that it is not possible to adjust the vertical distance of node. I have another question concerning this diagram. Can we put values for each link into the graph?

Comment: you'd have to be more specific about what you mean by "put values"... the value is already included in the tooltip on each link... and better to ask in a new question to make it more easily seen/used by other users

Comment: I have opened a new question as you suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52226342/refine-sankey-diagram-with-sankeynetwork. Thank you so much.